# trying to create my first project with laravel

Tags: php

I have this error in my system and I have not found the solution, could you help me

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v9.36.4, ..., v9.51.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.12.2].
- laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.36.3] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.12.2].
- league/flysystem[3.0.16, ..., 3.12.2] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.19.0, ..., v9.51.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Program Files\php-8.0.27\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

thanks

Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php-8.0.27\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment string "extension=fileinfo" in your php.ini file.